# Java getClass().equals() Comparison

Tags: java, object, equals

Why does this comparison using .getClass().equals() not work?

```
System.out.println("worldX: " + worldX.get(j).getClass());
System.out.println("-block: " + block.getClass());
System.out.println("Comparison: " + worldX.get(j).
        getClass().equals(bug.getClass()));
```

It prints out the following:

```
worldX: class aWorld.ABlock
-block: class aWorld.ABlock
Comparison: false
```

Edit:
Comparing different classes than those which I meant to compare.

Comment: Is block.getClass() is same as bug.getClass() ?

Comment: No, it's not. Sometimes you can miss the simplest things! Thanks for the (obviouse and obviously needed) help!

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the classes of `worldX` and `block`, but then comparing the former to `bug` (whatever that is).

If they *are* the same class and `getClass().equals()` returns `false`, one possibility is that there are multiple [class loaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) at play.

Comment: In the case where you're using multiple class loaders, you could use obj.getClass().getName().equals(otherObj.getClass().getName())